# How to keep interface view on page load?

Tags: jquery, variables, page-refresh, session-storage

On **submit event** I set do some things from the received **data**, which I would like to keep when I **refresh** the page and even when I do what I do ( with **if sessionStorage.token** ) it does't work. I did the exact same scenario with **Javascript** before and I swear it worked.

How this can be solved?  Please help me.

```
            // Initialize variables
            var $jUser = {};
            var $ajUsers = [];

            // Login POST 
            $('#frm-login').submit(function (e) {
                event.preventDefault()
                $loginButton.text('Please wait ...').prop('disabled')
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/login-user",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#frm-login').serialize(),
                dataType: "json"
            }).always(function (response) {
                $loginButton.text('Logging in').prop('disabled')
                console.log("Login", response)
                if (response.status == "error") {
                    $loginButton.removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
                    return
                }
                sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.token)
                if (sessionStorage.token) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/verify-user",
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.token
                        },
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).always(function (response) {
                        console.log("Auth", response)
                        if (response.status == "error") {
                            $loginButton.removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
                            return

                        }
                        $('#index-page').css('display', 'none')
                        $('#main-page').css('display', 'block')
                        $.getScript('/js/socket.js', function () {
                            console.log('script loaded');
                        });
                        $jUser = response.authData.user
                        $userAvatar.attr('src', $jUser.avatar)
                        $userFullname.text($jUser.first_name + ' ' + $jUser.last_name)
                        console.log($jUser)
                    })
                }
            })
        })
        console.log($jUser)
        if (sessionStorage.token) {
            function userSession() {
                $('#index-page').css('display', 'none')
                $('#main-page').css('display', 'block')
                $userAvatar.attr('src', $jUser.avatar)
                $userFullname.text($jUser.first_name + ' ' + $jUser.last_name)
                console.log('hello')
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you don't appear to be calling the function `userSession` anywhere. You are only defining it in your final token test.

Also, you are calling `always` on the jqXHR returned by the `$.ajax` call.  The `always` method will get called regardless of whether the ajax request is successful, and pass different arguments to the supplied function, depending on the status of the request.  See the [jQuery deferred method documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/).  I think you want to use the `success` attribute of the `$.ajax` parameters to achieve what you want.

Finally, I don't see where you are setting `$jUser`, but your code seems to assume it is persisted across page loads.  However, it is reset to an empty object (`{}`) each time your javascript gets executed (on each page load). You may wish to serialize it and save it in the `sessionStorage` object, so it will persist, then test for it and unserialize it to `$jUser` if it is stored.  Alternatively, you can call `verifyUser` on every page load using the stored token if it exists, which would be less efficient, but should work.

Without having access to the server for the Ajax calls, I can't test my changes to your code, but I'll post them anyway, and you can try them yourself.  Let me know if it helps.

```
// Initialize variables
var $jUser = {};
var $ajUsers = [];
var jUserJSON;

function failedLogin() {
    // handle failed logins
    $loginButton.removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
    $loginButton.text('Login').prop('disabled', false);
}

function ajaxError(url, testStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("The " + url + " Ajax request failed. status:" + textStatus + ', errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
}

function updatePageWithLogin() {
    $('#index-page').css('display', 'none');
    $('#main-page').css('display', 'block');
    $userAvatar.attr('src', $jUser.avatar);
    $userFullname.text($jUser.first_name + ' ' + $jUser.last_name);
    $.getScript('/js/socket.js', function () {
        console.log('script loaded');
    });
}

function verifyUser(token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/verify-user",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Auth", response)
            if (response.status == "error") {
                failedLogin();
                return;
            }

            $jUser = response.authData.user;

            // persist the $jUser object
            jUserJSON = JSON.stringify($jUser);
            sessionStorage.setItem('juser', jUserJSON);
            console.log("$jUser: " + jUserJSON);
            updatePageWithLogin();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ajaxError("/verify-user", textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This will get called whether the Ajax request succeeds or fails
        }
    });
}

// Login POST
$('#frm-login').submit(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $loginButton.text('Please wait ...').prop('disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/login-user",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#frm-login').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $loginButton.text('Logging in').prop('disabled', true);
            console.log("Login", response)
            if (response.status == "error") {
                failedLogin();
                return;
            }
            sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.token); // not sure this is necessary now
            if (response.token) { verifyUser(response.token) }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ajaxError("/login-user", textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This will get called whether the Ajax request succeeds or fails
        }
    })
});

jUserJSON = sessionStorage.getItem("juser");

if (jUserJSON) {
    // The user has already authenticated
    $jUser = JSON.parse(jUserJSON);
    updatePageWithLogin();
}

console.log("$jUser: " + jUserJSON);
```

Comment: this is where I am setting $jUser = response.authData.user it is the response from verifyUser. My intention is to store it in variable and call it in a function on page loads, not store that in sessionStorage only the token.

Comment: i kind of like the idea of verifying the user on each page load

Comment: I have implemented the alternative of, calling verifyUser on every page load, and when i refresh the page I always slightly see the index-page. Do you know why does that happens ?

Comment: ah i realized... the ajax takes time

Comment: Right, it slows down any page load too, especially in real network conditions that you can't control (ie. in production).  That's why I suggested storing the jUser data; because if it's in the session, then you know they've already authenticated.  Once they close the tab, the session will be reset, and jUser will be empty again.

Comment: Ah, I see where you were setting $jUser now.  I lost that line.  Answer updated...

Comment: If i would send responses in cookies from the server, could I access $jUser without needing to store it in sessionStorage that way ?. Would that be a better solution for this case ?

Comment: @July333 Storing authentication state in cookies is the most common practice.  The main difference being that cookies can persist across sessions, so it depends on your requirements.  I believe I answered your original question.  If so, please accept my answer.  Thank you.